# cannot resolve symbol при вводе values.put

Tags: android, sqlite

Впервые создаю базу SQLite в андроид (опираясь на документацию). В итоге `values.put` подчеркивает красным и пишет

> cannot resolve symbol put.

Также в этом же выражении не распознает класс `nwTABLE`.
`ContentValues` создаю и использую в отдельном классе

```
public final class newBASE {

public newBASE (){}

public static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
public static final String COMA_SEP = ",";
public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE" + nwTABLE.TABLE_NAME+ "("+nwTABLE._ID+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + nwTABLE.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMA_SEP
                + nwTABLE.TASK + TEXT_TYPE + COMA_SEP
                + nwTABLE.ANSWER + TEXT_TYPE + COMA_SEP +
                " )";
public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + nwTABLE.TABLE_NAME;

public static abstract class nwTABLE implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entire"
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mathprofi";
    public static final String TASK = "task";
    public static final String ANSWER = "answer";
}

public static class TABLEHELPER extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "newBASE.db";

    public TABLEHELPER (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }

    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int nerVersion){
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void onDowngrade  (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }       
}

TABLEHELPER mTABLEHELPER = new TABLEHELPER(getContext());

SQLiteDatabase db = mTABLEHELPER.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(nwTABLE.TASK, task);
values.put(nwTABLE.ANSWER, answer);

      }
```

Comment: Навскидку: сама таблица создается с ошибками. Там каждый лишний пробел может помешать ее созданию. Во-первых, таблица должна закрываться ");", а не " )". Во-вторых, не вижу где инициируется ваша переменная `nwTABLE._ID`, но пробел между ней и `"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"` не помешает :) По существу вопроса: а в каком месте вы создаете и наполняете `ContentValues`? Добавьте в вопрос, это неочевидно

Comment: ContentValues создаю в отдельном классе. А поскольку класс nwTABLE является абстрактным (так требует документация) я не создаю экземпляр класса

Comment: при этом, импорт интерфейса BaseColumns выполнен...

Comment: @Jarvis_J константа _ID находится в имплементируемом интерфейсе `BaseColumns` - это стандартная константа android для уникального идентификатора, но строка создания БД да, некорректная.

Comment: Одну ошибку уже увидел - ContentValues, надо было, все-таки, не там инициилизировать. Помещаю его в OnCreate и перестает подчеркивать put

Comment: А в чем некорректность строки создания БД?